# Retrieve Value of DropDownList by Index ID

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I am trying to retrieve the value of a dropdown list by specifying its indexid but I cant seem to find a way to accomplish this. I dont want it to be the selected value either, basically I need to go through the list, and then add it to an array. I can find all kinds of ways to get it based on the value but not by the index id anyone know how to do this? Im using c#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`string valueAtIndex = myComboBox.Items[SomeIndexValue].Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `lstWhatever.SelectedIndex`?

Since the object supports `IEnumerable`, you can use `foreach` to loop through, if that is your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 List<String> theList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            theList.Add(item.ToString());
        }
```

Where comboBox1 is your dropdown list and i assumed you are talking about a windows forms project.

Or, if you want to us Index Id:

```
List<string> theList = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                theList.Add(comboBox1.Items[i].ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

String valueAtIndex = myComboBox.Items[myComboBox.SelectedIndex].ToString();

Comment: Or any index can go inside the brackets

Comment: That should be `myComboBox.Items[myComboBox.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString();`